# domain subfolder redirect to domain using .htaccess in wordpress

Tags: apache, redirect, dns

I have a wordpress blog which was running on example1.com/folder or www.example1.com/folder. Now I have to redirect it to example2.com or www.example2.com . How can I do this using .htaccess?

Comment: I have the following code in my .htaccess file:
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www.)?)example1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ http://www.example2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This checks if it receives traffic for `www.example1.com` or `example.com` and if so sends anything going to `/folder/.*` to `www.example2.com/.*` For example:

`www.example1.com/folder/blah.html` becomes `www.example2.com/blah.html`

Comment: I m sorry but the redirection not working. I want to redirect page www.greatwayonine.com/np or any of the folder behind the greatwayonine.com to www.onlinegreatway.com. But the page not found error still occuring. Any solution @Peter?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www.)?)greatwayonine.com [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.onlinegreatway.com/$1 [R=301,L]`
Assuming that the same folder structure is in place, i.e. onlinegreatway.com/np exists as well.